# In async http requests duration for every single request is not shown correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, async-await, axios

I am testing async http requests using `NodeJs 14` and `AWS Lambda`.
So, I am doing 100 asynchronous http GET requests and trying measure duration for every single request. Total duration: 5632.74 ms.

```
  async makeRequests() {
    const axList = []

    for (const item of this.targets) {
        const {url, method} = item
        const config = {url, method}

        const stat = {
            startTime: this.getTime(),
            duration: 0,
            status: 0,
            response: null
        }

        const ax = axios.create()

        ax.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
            config.headers['startTime'] = this.getTime().toString();

            return config
        })

        ax.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
            const currentTime = this.getTime()
            const startTime = response.config.headers['startTime']
            response.headers['duration'] = (currentTime - startTime).toString()

            return response
        })

        const axItem = ax.request(config)
            .then((resp) => {
                const {status, data} = resp;

                stat.duration = resp.headers['duration']
                stat.response = data
                stat.status = status
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
            .finally(() => {
                this.reponses.push(stat)
            })

        axList.push(axItem)
    }

    await axios.all(axList)

    return this.reponses
}
```

In this case All requests are asynchronous but `duration` for every request is not correct or unexpected. Response logs:

```
  {
    "startTime": 1634169624637,
    "duration": "4063",
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
  },
  {
    "startTime": 1634169624638,
    "duration": "4120",
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
  }, 
  // .... + 97 logs
  {
    "startTime": 1634169624837,
    "duration": "5341",
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
      "data": "OK"
    }
  }
```

But when I do request synchronously by blocking every request using await inside the loop. I get real duration time for every request.

```
    async makeRequests() {
        for (const item of this.targets) {
            const {url, method} = item
            const config = {url, method}

            const stat = {
                startTime: this.getTime(),
                duration: 0,
                status: 0,
                response: null
            }

            const ax = axios.create()

            ax.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
                config.headers['startTime'] = this.getTime().toString();

                return config
            })

            ax.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
                const currentTime = this.getTime()
                const startTime = response.config.headers['startTime']
                response.headers['duration'] = (currentTime - startTime).toString()

                return response
            })

            await ax.request(config)
                .then((resp) => {
                    const {status, data} = resp;

                    stat.duration = resp.headers['duration']
                    stat.response = data
                    stat.status = status
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    this.reponses.push(stat)
                })
        }

        return this.reponses
    }
```

The duration for every request is realistic now. But it works synchronously which is bad and Total duration much more.

```
{
    "startTime": 1634162343040,
    "duration": "95",
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
},
{
    "startTime": 1634162343135,
    "duration": "44",
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
},
// .... + 97 logs
{
    "startTime": 1634162349596,
    "duration": "83",
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
}
```

**What can I do for getting correct duration time for every request but at the same time it should be `asynchronously` ?**

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the root cause of issue. With first method everthing is okay. The problem was in memory usage. My lambda memory was set `128 MB` and it was not enough for executing `100` request asyncronously.

So, I have increased memory to `10240 MB`and reduced request count to `20`. Then response is expected and all requests are asyncronously.

Response logs:

```
{
    "startTime": 1634334790699,
    "duration": 32,
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
},{
    "startTime": 1634334790704,
    "duration": 28,
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
},{
    "startTime": 1634334790701,
    "duration": 31,
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
},{
    "startTime": 1634334790708,
    "duration": 25,
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
},{
    "startTime": 1634334790706,
    "duration": 28,
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
},{
    "startTime": 1634334790698,
    "duration": 36,
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
},{
    "startTime": 1634334790702,
    "duration": 33,
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
},{
    "startTime": 1634334790696,
    "duration": 40,
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
},{
    "startTime": 1634334790703,
    "duration": 34,
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
},{
    "startTime": 1634334790701,
    "duration": 38,
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
},{
    "startTime": 1634334790700,
    "duration": 43,
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
},{
    "startTime": 1634334790698,
    "duration": 47,
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
},{
    "startTime": 1634334790705,
    "duration": 41,
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
},{
    "startTime": 1634334790704,
    "duration": 42,
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
},{
    "startTime": 1634334790702,
    "duration": 45,
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
},{
    "startTime": 1634334790699,
    "duration": 48,
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
},{
    "startTime": 1634334790709,
    "duration": 39,
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
},{
    "startTime": 1634334790706,
    "duration": 42,
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
},{
    "startTime": 1634334790707,
    "duration": 42,
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
},{
    "startTime": 1634334790705,
    "duration": 116,
    "status": 200,
    "response": {
        "data": "OK"
    }
}
```